# Is it mandatory to include .gitignore file to my repository on git?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I do not have any files that must be ignored.
My doubt is so shud we add a gitignore file to github repo even when we have nothing to ignore

Comment: Im pretty sure there will always be a file that should be ignored(libs that you should not git add, some files with settings like secret_keys, etc. - ofc it depends on which language you use). But if for some reason you are sure that there are no files to ignore, then just dont add gitignore.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not mandatory.

.gitignore is used to make sure nobody using the repository is committing files that are "forbidden" (i.e. that should never be a part of a commit).

Typical examples are: binaries, logs, autogenerated meta files, files that are generated and are strongly dependent on the build environment or the specific machine/user.

You may have a git repository without any gitignore file. You may add one later on in the project life.

If you wish to "ignore" files locally and not share this list with other repositories, use `.git/info/exclude` instead of a gitignore file

Answer (score 0):

It is not, as the name says "gitignore" it is for files that you are not going to "need" to run your project or files that are just going to interfere on how your program runs.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Not really: a gitignore serves the purpose to avoid committing and pushing artifacts: autogenerated files and binaries expecially should never be part of a commit/repository. So you use the gitignore to avoid committing them by mistake.

Answer (score -2):

It is not mandatory to push the .gitignore file. If your working in a team then pushing the gitignore file might cause issues for the other people who might want to pull the project and commit such files.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Avoiding to push a a gitignore file is not the same as not have it. By how you describe it, it seems you are using the gitignore file in a way that is not intended to. A gitignore file, when is created, _should_ be pushed. To ignore files on your local working machine use `.git/info/exclude` instead.

Comment: It's very much always preferrable to add a `.gitignore` if you're working with other people. You do **NOT** want anybody pushing their editor config, or local logs, or derived files (e.g., compiled ones). That should be uniform between the team, rather than enforced on a per-user basis. It means that even if everybody keeps a good commit hyegine, a new committer might still push anything that's undesirable by accident. The `.gitignore` should therefore be coordinated and shared with the team.